# Nearest singular matrix

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-rank, svd

Let the SVD of $A \in \mathbb R^{{n}*{n}} $ be given as $A=\sum_{i=0}^n \sigma_{i}u_{i}v_{i}^{T}$ where $\sigma_{1}\gt \sigma_{2}>{...}>\sigma_{n-1}=\sigma_{n}>0 $

Compute a matrix $B$ such that $B$ is the nearest singular matrix to $A$ in $2-norm$ and rank of $(A-B)=3$.

Here by nearest singular matrix we mean that the matrix $B$ will be of rank $n-1$, But how to form such a matrix $B$, such that the rank of $(A-B)=3$?

Please can anyone help me to solve the prblem??

Comment: You are looking for the [Eckart-Young-Mirsky theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation#Basic_low-rank_approximation_problem).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Suppose, $B = \sum_{i=1}^{n-3}\sigma_{i}u_iv_i^T + 0u_{n-2}v_{n-2}^{T} + 0u_{n-1}v_{n-1}^{T} +0u_{n}v_{n}^{T}$, then $A - B = \sum_{i=n-2}^{n}\sigma_iu_iv_i^{T}. $ Thus, rank of $A-B = 3$.

Useful theorem: Let $k < n$, where $n$ is the rank of $A$ as specified in the question and
$A_k =\sum_{i=1}^{k}\sigma_iu_iv_i^T$
then $min_{rank(B)=k}\|A − B\|_2 = \|A − A_k\|_2 = σ_{k+1}$.

Comment: Here rank of $(A-B)$ is $3$, but the problem is I want the nearest singular matrix which will be of rank $n-1$, but here $B$ is of rank $n-3$.

Comment: Suppose, $B = \sum_{i=1}^{n-3}\sigma_{i}u_iv_i^T + 0u_{n-2}v_{n-2}^{T} + 0.5\sigma_{n-1}u_{n-1}v_{n-1}^{T} +0.5\sigma_nu_{n}v_{n}^{T}$. Then $A-B$ is rank $3$ and $B$ is rank $n-1$.

Comment: yah...It's correct... I've got the answer.. thanks a lot..